# Updating Opera browser through command line (Windows)

Tags: windows

I'm writing a script that suppose to, among others, update Opera browser on the machine it's running on. Is there a way to update it through cmd? Is there a universal way to do so for any chromium based browser?

Comment: What did you try? Please add the commands.

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

One you use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Opera) to install Opera. Upgrading is also supported:

```
choco upgrade opera
```